# Trouble with layout, need scroll down to see footer

Tags: css, html

**This is my .html file** with a wrapper that contains the header with the menu - sidebar - a div for the content :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header id="header"> Header - Menu</header>

     <div class = "central-body">

        <div id = "sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div id = "main-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>

    </div>

     <footer> </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is my css**:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

html, body{
height: 100%;
}

body{
background-color: black;
}

.wrapper{   
height: 100%;
}

#header{
background-color: blue;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}

.central-body{
height: 100%;
width:100%; 
background-color: purple;
}

#sidebar{
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
}

#main-content{
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
}

footer{
width:100%;
height: 40px;
background-color: red;
}
```

My problem is that i have to scroll down "40px" to see my footer, even if there are few words in "sidebar" and "main-content". How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you need the main content and siderbar to be of the equal height ? It will the height of the longer content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `.central-body`height 100% minus the height of the header and the footer like this:

`height:calc(100% - 80px) //header 40px + footer 40px`

We're using `calc` for this to work.

(This will also work if we do the calc on the `.wrapper`)

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/vLWRgq?editors=110) is an working example

Code:

```
.central-body {   
    height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's what i was looking for :D 

I havent read about this solution anywhere while i was searching on google, thank you again for your time ^^

Comment: No problem glad it helped!